# C# Cast concrete class variables at run time (Dependency Injection)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to implement dependency injection in my project to connect with SQL server for unit testing.
I have used the inbuilt abstract classes came in SQL library and created my own Mock classes for SqlCommand,SqlConnection and SqlTransaction.
Below are the my classes.

I'm unable to use SqlCommand property(SqlParameterCollection) method which is named as AddWithValue in my program.cs file at compile time.

I'm getting below error

**'DbParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no accessible extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'DbParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Object DbParameterCollection resides in abstract class DbCommand however the given Object which has the AddWithValue method resides in concrete class which is SqlCommand.

How can i tell the compiler that AddWithValue method should be called on the property of class SqlCommand and not on DBCommand.

Here are all my classes.

As i'm new to this i haven't found anything injecting concrete classes at runtime using reflection or there might be some other ways to do it.

SQLWrapper.cs

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class SQLWrapper
    {
        private Context _ctx;
        private string _referenceID;
        private string _connectionKey;
        private static string _connectionString;
        private int _timeout = 180;

        public SQLWrapper(Context ctx, string referenceID, string connectionKey)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
            _referenceID = referenceID;
            _connectionKey = connectionKey;
        }

        public async Task<Error> GetConnectingStringAsync()
        {
           // Gets the connection string from config
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the statement.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ctx"></param>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<Error> ExecuteStatementAsync()
        {
            Error error = null;
            try
            {
                error = await GetConnectingStringAsync();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    return error;
                }

                using (_ctx.connection)
                {
                    _ctx.connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                    _ctx.command.CommandTimeout = _timeout;
                    try
                    {
                        await _ctx.connection.OpenAsync();
                        _ctx.command.Connection = _ctx.connection;
                        _ctx.command.Prepare();
                        _ctx.transaction = _ctx.connection.BeginTransaction();
                        await _ctx.command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        _ctx.transaction.Commit();
                        return null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (_ctx.transaction != null)
                        {
                            _ctx.transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                        return error;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return error;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

MockCommand.cs

```
namespace DAL
{
    class MockCommand : DbCommand
    {
        private string _commandText;
        private int _commandTimeout;
        private DbConnection _DbConnection;

        public MockSQL Connection { get; set; }
        public override string CommandText { get => _commandText; set => _commandText = value; }
        public override int CommandTimeout { get => _commandTimeout; set => _commandTimeout = value; }
        public override CommandType CommandType { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override bool DesignTimeVisible { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override UpdateRowSource UpdatedRowSource { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        protected override DbConnection DbConnection { get => _DbConnection; set => _DbConnection = value; }

        new public SqlParameterCollection Parameters { get; }
        protected override DbParameterCollection DbParameterCollection => null;

        protected override DbTransaction DbTransaction { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override void Cancel()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int ExecuteNonQuery()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override object ExecuteScalar()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Prepare()
        {
            return;
        }

        protected override DbParameter CreateDbParameter()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override DbDataReader ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

MockSQL.cs

```
namespace DAL
{
    class MockSQL : DbConnection
    {
        private string _connectionString;
        public override string ConnectionString { get => ""; set => _connectionString = value; }

        public override string Database => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override string DataSource => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override string ServerVersion => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override ConnectionState State => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Open()
        {
            return;
        }

        protected override DbTransaction BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            return new MockTransaction();
        }

        protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

MockTransaction.cs

```
namespace DAL
{
    class MockTransaction : DbTransaction
    {
        public override IsolationLevel IsolationLevel => throw new NotImplementedException();

        protected override DbConnection DbConnection => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override void Commit()
        {
            return;
        }

        public override void Rollback()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Context.cs

```
 public class Context
    {
        public DbConnection connection;
        public DbCommand command;
        public DbTransaction transaction;
        public ICongigRPC config;
    }
```

ContextInitializer.cs

```
public static class ContextInitializer
    {
        public static Context InitCtx()
        {
            return new Context()
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(),
                command = new SqlCommand(),
                transaction = null
            };
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
Context ctx = MockContextInitializer.MockInitCtx();
            ctx.command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERMAPPING WHERE OldMemberID = @OldMemberID;";
            ctx.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldMemberID", "1234");
            SQLWrapper wrapper = new SQLWrapper(ctx, "123", "123");
            wrapper.ExecuteStatementAsync();
```

Comment: by casting ????

Comment: This is not Code Review, but ... what purpose do these classes have? Anyway, as the error states, the member declared as `DbParameterCollection` _doesn't_ have an `AddWithValue()`  method, which you shouldn't use anyway. It won't work with non-mock classes either. Just use `Add(new XxxParameter(...))`.

Comment: Rather than trying to create a mock of the framework-provided SQL tools, it's more common to create a data access layer that **wraps** those tools and implements more generic, context-specific interfaces.

Comment: I vaguely remember "AddWithValue" being somewhat deprecated. Why not "simply": `var parameter = command.CreateParameter(); parameter.ParameterName = "@Key"; parameter.Value = "whatever"; command.Parameters.Add(parameter);`?

Comment: @CodeCaster
I'm creating these classes for unit testing where i can return sample mock response for my business logic.
I have learned from internet that we can achieve unit testing using dependency injection hence tried to follow that without using any third party package for unit testing.

Comment: @DanielMann you means creating a data access layer which will decide the behavior of objects at runtime?
Is there any example? As i'm getting confused by looking onto your statement.